# Using NSFetchedResultsController Without UITableView

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is it wrong to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` purely for data management, i.e., without using it to feed a `UITableView`?

I have a to-many relationship in a Core Data iPhone app. Whenever data in that relationship changes, I need to perform a calculation which requires that data to be sorted. In Apple's standard Department/Employees example, this would be like determining the median salary in a given Department. Whenever an Employee is added to or removed from that Department, or an Employee's salary changes, the median calculation would need to be performed again.

Keeping data sorted and current and getting notifications when it changes sounds like a great job for `NSFetchedResultsController`. The only "problem" is that I'm not using a `UITableView`. In other words, I'm not displaying sorted Employees in a `UITableView`. I just want an up-to-date sorted array of Employees so I can analyze them behind the scenes. (And, of course, I don't want to write a bunch of code that duplicates much of `NSFetchedResultsController`.)

Is it a bad idea to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` purely for data management, i.e., without using it to feed a `UITableView`? I haven't seen this done anywhere, and thought I might be missing something.

Comment: As noted below, using a fetched results controller in this fashion is not a problem. You should remember that "premature optimization is the root of all evil." Since it's the easiest method for you to implement try it and see if it works in this particular instance and then try something else only when you've tested and found it insufficient.

Comment: Hard to argue against @TechZen's advice here. I am in the bowls of Core Data so much that I tend to see it's internals differently.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the consensus is that this isn't a bad idea from a design point of view, but it might have performance implications that are best evaluated with tests. I wish I could accept all the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would not call it bad but definitely "heavy".

It would be less memory and CPU to watch for saves via the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and do the calculation there.  The notification will come with three `NSArray` instances in its `userInfo` and you can then use a simple `NSPredicate` against those arrays to see if any employee that you care about has changed and respond.

This is part of what the `NSFetchedResultsController` does under the covers.  However you would be avoiding the other portions of the `NSFetchedResultsController` that you don't care about or need.

### Heavy

`NSFetchedResultsController` does more processing than just watch for saved objects.  It handles deltas, makes calls to its delegates, etc.  I am **not** saying it is bad in any way shape or form.  What I am saying is that if you *only* care about when objects have changed in your relationship, you can do it pretty easily by just watching for the notifications.

### Memory

In addition, there is no reason to retain anything since you are already holding onto the "Department" entity and therefore access its relationships.  Holding onto the child objects "just in case" is a waste of memory.  Let Core Data manage the memory, that is part of the reason for using it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and suggestion! If using NSFetchedResultsController isn't bad, then this sounds like a performance issue. In some instances, it would be useful for me to keep the sorted data around for other user-initiated calculations that require it. I'm assuming that fetchedObjects is where most of the memory burden comes from. If so, I'll lose the memory savings by retaining the sorted data as part of handling the save notification. But what is the extra CPU usage you're referring to? Is that from using a fetch in NSFetchedResultsController instead of a relationship accessor?

Comment: You use fetches to find objects based on attributes. To find relationships, you walk the object graph by calling following the relationships of fetched objects. Walking the graph is more efficient because the context only needs faults (i.e. objects with no attribute data loaded) to follow relationships.

Comment: The only reason I would hold onto the sorted "Employee" objects is to avoid resorting them as part of each user-initiated calculation.

Comment: Personally in that case I would create a convenience method that returns the employees sorted instead of retaining them but that is arguably a personal preference.

Comment: I like that approach; that's what I'm currently doing. :) Well, actually I filter the "employees" first and sort the results. The filtered data set can be relatively small. So I thought: "Might it be smarter to filter/sort the large data set once and cache the small array of results rather than repeatedly filter the large data set every time I need the sorted subset? I could create a class to manage the filtered/sorted data and use change notifications from the MOC to keep everything up-to-date. Hmm... Isn't there a class that essentially does that?" And thus my question was born.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using `NSFetchedResultsController` without a view. Your use case sounds like a good reason to not re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like an appropriate use of NSFetchedResultController.  it might be a bit overkill, as its primary use IS to help populate and keep up to date tableViews, but if you are willing to put up with the added complexity, there is no reason to not use it as such.  Correct use of notifications would be the other method and it is just as complex i would estimate.