# What is the most efficient way to observe managed object context changes for particular entity types on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Apologies if this has been discussed to death elsewhere but I could not find a question that addresses my query directly.

I am working on an application that downloads objects from a remote server in JSON format and converts the result into core data objects.

For a while I have been using `NSFetchedResultsController` to observe object changes for particular entity types with a filter `NSPredicate` applied. The aim here is to be informed of changes only when managed objects that meet certain criteria have been added, modified or deleted.

I am aware of the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` of `NSManagedObjectContext`, however my understanding is that the `-userInfo` dictionary contains all object changes, regardless of entity.

My fears may be unfounded, but as I am not using `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage a `UITableView`, am I being wasteful in employing the class for this purpose?

Is there a better way of being notified when objects of a particular entity type and property values have been added, modified or deleted?

Many Thanks.

P.s. I am aware of the availability of `NSArrayController` in Cocoa which seems to contain the features I require, although I have not experimented with it. This class is not available for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've use `NSFetchedResultsController` in the past to keep track of changes to Core Data objects that I'm interested in. There's nothing that says you have to tie it to a UITableView implementation.

That said, you might want to look at this question: [Using NSFetchedResultsController Without UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216685/using-nsfetchedresultscontroller-without-uitableview)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
```

it provide a notification whenever a managed object in the context is inserted/updated/deleted.

or

, you can use a `custom NSManagedObject` subclass

Comment: +1, in there, check the userInfo object and filter out the change you are interested in. If you use custom classes for the entity, you can use isKindOfClass, else check obj.entity.name

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping that some mechanism might exist where I could set an entity type, a predicate (such as exclude objects with a property set to a particular value) and then be notified **only** when an object matching this criteria is added, modified or deleted. I'd rather not have to check the user info dictionary of the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` at each point in the system where I am interested in managed objects.  Does anything wrap up these checks other than `NSFetchedResultsController`, or am I going to have to put something together myself?