# Display a Core Data count in a UILabel, constantly updating

Tags: ios, core-data, uilabel, nsmanagedobject

Given a Core Data Entity called `Book`, what would be the best way to get a count of how many `Book`s there are, in total, and display this total in a UILabel? The `UILabel` would need to update as book objects were created/deleted (potentially by other objects elsewhere in the app).

Actually counting the books isn't difficult. My question is more how do we get updates as this count changes?

- Perhaps override willSave/delete/etc on the `Book` managed object?
- KVO (but how do we do this on the entire Entity rather than a single object?)
- Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, you could subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and try to analyze it. I see two disadvantages in this. First, this notification is called a lot and on any change in any object. Calls will not literally happen at the moment when the change happens, but still any change is reported in this notification. Second, the subscriber needs to know all the contexts where the new Book is created. You might think of subscribing to this notification with nil for context to receive this notification for all the contexts. But this is even more overwhelming and dangerous, and not recommended by Apple (you will receive this notification also for the contexts that you don’t own).

What I would recommend for each place that creates a Book to have its own notification. Like `XYBookAddControllerDidAddBookNotification`, `XYBookListControllerDidDeleteBookNotification` and so on. In this case:

1. The place that displays counts doesn’t have to know anything about the context where change was made.
2. The place that displays will only respond to specific add/remove events instead of analyzing heavy traffic of objects-did-change notification.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for the notification (`NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`) relating to core data changes and update your UI from that.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDataModelChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:myManagedObjectContext];

- (void)handleDataModelChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
  NSSet *updatedObjects  = notification.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
  NSSet *deletedObjects  = notification.userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey];
  NSSet *insertedObjects = notification.userInfo[NSInsertedObjectsKey];  

  // update your UI with the new count
}
```

NB: dont forget to remove yourself,

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Be very aggressive about returning early from this method. This notification is sent a _lot_

Answer (score 1):

You could create a *NSFetchedResultsController* to fetch *book* objects, then implement it's delegate methods. Reference:

[NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)

Comment: Thanks, but wary of doing this for the reasons explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3216781/1641835

Comment: I don't believe that a performance impact of maintaining one additional NSFetchedResultsController will be noticeable, but it of course depends on your data.