# IOS/Xcode/Coredata: What is equivalent of [[self tableView] reloadData]; when there is no tableview?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, reload

There must be a way to update a UIViewController or view in the absence of a tableView using NSFetchedResultsController?

In this case there are some labels and a picture.  I just want to refresh them with the latest data from managedobjectcontext.

Thank you.

Comment: See the answer by Marcus Zarra: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216685/using-nsfetchedresultscontroller-without-uitableview

Comment: That is good discussion but doesn't give any code equivalent to [tableview reload].  This is reloading from the managed object context btw so is not using the heavy part of core data.

Comment: You are correct, it does discuss however that you can respond to notifications when your data has changed and act accordingly. So whenever your VC receives eg an `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, it could call `setNeedsDisplay` for your subviews that display the data.

Comment: Ok.  I will try this.  I have to learn how to use notifications as this is new to me.

Comment: sounds like setNeedsDisplay does not update elements from the NSManagedObjectContext...it is more for drawing.  I really need to figure out how to refresh the screen. This is so trivial in web programming...seems weird that it is so complicated in IOS.

Comment: Well, first you need to pull the update string for your `UILabel` from the userInfo of the notification (`NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotification` is probably better), then you can call `setNeedsDisplay`. Sorry if I wasn't clearer earlier.

Comment: There is no 'refresh the screen' on iOS. You created the UI elements and set them to their initial values based on the initial state of the data, and you're responsible for updating them when that data changes.

Comment: Finally, someone explains this in plain English.  Does that mean I have to update them individually as in nameLabel = entityclass.attribute?

Comment: OK.  You update them when data changes but how?  Even if you use the delegate pattern don't you have to do something to force a reload of the screen using the new data?

Answer (score 1):

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

will redraw the view.

```
[myView setNeedsLayout];
```

will update the layout.

Edit: After reading the comments, it's clear what you're trying to do. It's called **UI Data bindings** and it's not natively supported in iOS. You can search github for possible open source implementations, but I can't guarantee or recommend any since I haven't used any. My suggestion is to encapsulate the pulling and displaying of data in a function and simply call it to reload everything, especially if the reloading of the data is a result of an event:

```
-(void)loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt{
      NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription
                  entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
      NSArray* data = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

      User* firstUser = data[0];

      self.labelName.text = firstUser.name;
      self.labelPhoneNumber.text = firstUser.phoneNumber;
      //...
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
     //...
     [self loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt];
}

-(void)someEventDidOccurThatShouldReloadData:(id)sender{
     [self loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt];
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put setNeeds Display as a method in view?  And will this pull latest data from managed object context?

Comment: Does it work with NSFetchedResultsController and CoreData to pull latest data in data driven screen?

Comment: Nope, you have to do that on the application level.

Comment: I have tried setNeedsDisplay but get the following error: No visible @interface for itemDetailVC (my view as you call it) declares the selector setNeedsDisplay.  Is this part of a larger class; VC is descended from NSobject.

Comment: Ok figured out syntax for setNeedsDisplay.  Am using [self.itemLabel setNeedsDisplay] and no longer get error message.  However page is not updating with new data.

Comment: I tried this and no luck.  Of note, the line User* firstUser = data[0]; gives a warning unused variable 'firstUser'  Since the updating is supposed to happen when you save and dismiss the modal edit screen, in the save I've included a code block that successfully fires [detail loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt] as evidenced by the log.  (I also tried firing [detail viewdidload] from the code block and calling loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt directly from the other file .)  However, although they all fire the detailVC still shows old data until you go back to table and then reload.

Answer (score 1):

What a table view's `reloadData` does is it calls e.g. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` a number of times, which is where you yourself add code to set the content of your labels, etc.

Similarly, you yourself will have to set the content of the labels and other UI outlets. `setNeedsDisplay` will only redraw the screen, not update your UI elements with data. You will have to do this "manually" in your controller.

Make a method called something like `reloadViewData` and reset all the labels with the current data object(s). This is not much work because presumably you have already written this code for the initial view setup. Just factor it out into this method and call it both for view setup and view update.

Comment: I created method and call it before dismissing controller however am getting same result.  Do I need to place setNeedsDisplay at bottom of method?  setNeedsDisplay is not working for me currently as per comment below.

Comment: Have create one method reloadViewData that sets all the labels equal to their value in the managedobjectcontext.  Do I have to do setNeedsDisplay for each one as in [self.itemLabel setNeedsDisplay];[self.itemDetail setNeedsDisplay]; etc?  Have tried it with just itemLabel and still not showing new data.

Comment: You can forget about setNeedsDisplay. If the data is not shown, it has another reason. What you do in `loadDataFromDatabaseAndDisplayIt` is correct, just step through your code and see if you have the expected data.

Comment: I stepped through the code and after doing the fetch, the name and for that matter all other data is null.  There seems to be a mismatch here as fetch without predicate should return whole recordset rather than this particular record.  In any case it shows up as null.